# Display errors in JUnit failure trace

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver

I use Selenium Web Driver in Eclipse with JUnit. I need create simple checking if some text exists on the page - if it is, than I need generate error. I want this error to be displayed in JUnit failure trace. This is my code:

```
public class Check  {
@Rule
public ErrorCollector errCollector = new ErrorCollector();

@FindBy(tagName="body")
@CacheLookup
private WebElement titl;
@FindBy(partialLinkText="Exception")
@CacheLookup
private WebElement excep;


public void check_false(String t, String r) {
        try {
             String bodyText = titl.getText();
             Assert.assertFalse("Exception found", bodyText.contains(t)); }
         catch (AssertionError e) {
             System.err.println(r + ": " + e.getMessage());
             System.out.println(excep.getText());
             errCollector.addError(e);   
            }    
          }
```

If I get error, it is displayed in Eclipse consol, but test if shown as without error in JUnit and no exception message is displayed. How can I make checking properly?

Answer (score 0):

I use

> AssertJUnit.assertFalse("Exception found", bodyText.contains(t));

It's from http://testng.org/doc/index.html
see http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/AssertJUnit.html

Within eclipse when my test fails, in the junit window I get the stackstrace.  Have never tried collecting the errors.  It would throw an

> AssertionFailedError

if the test fails but if you catch it, I don't know if the stacktrace will be in the JUnit window.

Comment: I discover this way in this video training - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAmII54wpAY&feature=player_embedded.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be quite what you're after, in which case ignore it, but you can simply [fail it](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#fail%28java.lang.String%29) and supply an optional message as to why.

```
public void checkText(String actual, String expected){
  try{
    if(!expected.equals(actuals){
      fail("Expected : [ " expected + " ] , actual [" + actual + "]"
  }catch(SomeOtherException soe){
      fail(soe.getMessage());
  }
 }
```

Comment: I use this, but it is not what I really mean and need